# TypeScript's dictionary type in Mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Dictionary type in TS looks like:

```
{
   [key: string]: string;
}
```

However, while declaring my own schema in mongoose, it fails.

```
const users = new Schema({
   [key: string]: String,
});
```

I also tried just:

```
const users = new Schema({
   [String]: String,
});
```

But doesn't work neither. Help appreciated

**Edit**: I just want the `users` to be an object with keys as `string` and their values as `string`. Also the object can't be empty

Comment: Have you tried just using `key: String`?

Comment: @Luca This is weird because when I send post request api overwrites my whole object into just `{ _id: someRandomHash }`...

Comment: Are you passing it not-undefined data through the other keys? Ofc it's going to *add* the _id field

Comment: You cannot define a type were a parameter is required.

Comment: Gents, I just want the `users` to be object that keys are strings and it's not empty object. Looking forward for any hints

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a type as a parameter to a function or initializer. You can assign it to a variable and pass the variable like this:

```
interface MySchema {
  [key: string]: string
}

let data: MySchema = {
  v1: 'abc',
  v2: '123'
}

const users = new Schema(data);
```

If `Schema` is a generic, you could use the diamond operator like this:

```
interface MySchema {
  [key: string]: string
}

const users = new Schema<MySchema>({
  v1: 'abc',
  v2: '123'
});
```

Comment: I can use interfaces in moongose?!

Comment: Yes, It was just an example. My question was how to do something like interface from typescript in mongoose :P

Comment: You can use interfaces in any typescript file.